# Conditions among different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
            A   B    C
0  2002-01-13  18  120
1  2002-01-13   7  150
2  2002-01-13  11  130
3  2002-01-13  26  140
4  2002-01-14  13  180
5  2002-01-14  25  165
6  2002-01-14   9  150
7  2002-01-14   4  190
```

I have this `df`.

I apply this code:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['B'].sub(10).abs().groupby(df['A']).idxmin()]
```

Which result in `df2`:

```
            A   B    C
2  2002-01-13  11  130
6  2002-01-14   9  150
```

Now I want to create a new df3, selecting rows in `df` that satisfy next conditions, per each `A` group:

- `df["C"] = df2["C"] + 20` (in case of `2002-01-13` group, 130 + 20 = 150).
- If it doesn´t exist in `df` row that satisfy `df["C"] = df2["C"] + 20`, take the first lower value (in case of `2002-01-14` group, 150 + 20 = 170. Since 170 doesn´t exist, select the next lower, it means 165).

`df3` output should be:

```
            A   B    C
1  2002-01-13   7  150
5  2002-01-14  25  165
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('C'),df2.assign(C=df.C+20).sort_values('C'),on='C',by='A',direction ='forward').dropna().drop_duplicates('A',keep='last')
Out[553]: 
            A  B_x    C   B_y
3  2002-01-13    7  150  11.0
5  2002-01-14   25  165   9.0
```

Update

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('C').reset_index(),df2.assign(C=df2.C+20).sort_values('C'),on='C',by='A',direction ='forward').dropna().drop_duplicates('A',keep='last').set_index('index')
Out[606]: 
                A  B_x    C   B_y
index                            
1      2002-01-13    7  150  11.0
5      2002-01-14   25  165   9.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I have repeated question accidentally. Anyway, I want df3 output such as I´ve written: Rows 1 and 5, not 3 and 5

Comment: @Tie_24 so the index is important ?

Comment: Yes, it is important in this case

Comment: @Tie_24 it is easy to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

With a lambda and if statement. Used to get the indices then pull the values. If no match for +20 get the maximum value below C+20.

Full Code to duplicate example an improve:

import pandas as pd

```
# build op data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
A = [pd.Timestamp('2002-01-13'), pd.Timestamp('2002-01-13'), pd.Timestamp('2002-01-13'), pd.Timestamp('2002-01-13'),
     pd.Timestamp('2002-01-14'), pd.Timestamp('2002-01-14'), pd.Timestamp('2002-01-14'), pd.Timestamp('2002-01-14')]
B = [18, 7, 11, 26, 13, 25, 9, 4]
C = [120, 150, 130, 140, 180, 165, 150, 190]

df['A'] = A
df['B'] = B
df['C'] = C
print(df)

# build df2
df2 = df.loc[df['B'].sub(10).abs().groupby(df['A']).idxmin()]
print(df2)

# find indices in df that meet op criteria
df_ind = df2.apply(lambda row: ((df.A == row.A) & (df.C == row.C+20)).idxmax() if ((df.A == row.A) & (df.C == row.C+20)).sum() > 0 else (df.C.loc[(df.C < row.C+20) & (df.A == row.A)]).idxmax(), axis=1)
print(df_ind)

2    1
6    5

# Build df3
df3 = df.loc[df_ind.tolist(), :]
print(df3)
```

Results:

```
           A   B    C
1 2002-01-13   7  150
5 2002-01-14  25  165
```